# Need help tuning a select query to change a Match/Against clause to a Like clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, string-matching, sql-like

I'm currently trying to incorporate a `LIKE` clause into my SQL select statement and take out the associating MATCH/AGAINST clause.

Ive tried many different variations of it and feel that I'm missing something since none have seemed to work yet.

The full php Page is

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['searchQuery']))
    {
          require_once('config.inc.php');
          $search_query=$_POST['searchQuery'];

          $sql = 'SELECT * from tbl_fish where MATCH(fish_name,size_name,cat_name) AGAINST(:search_query)';

          $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
          $statement->bindParam(':search_query', $search_query, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $statement->execute();
          if($statement->rowCount())
          {
                $row_all = $statement->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                header('Content-type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($row_all);
          }  
          elseif(!$statement->rowCount())
          {
              echo "no rows";
          }
    }
?>
```

I've tried statements like this

```
 $sql = 'SELECT * from tbl_fish WHERE (fish_name LIKE '%'searchQuery'%')';
```

But I have yet to come up with a working one. These results are being queried from an android application so I'm wondering if I'm missing something more than just changing that one statement. I was following a tutorial for this and it all works except when I try to change the parameters for the query.

Hoping to get some feedback from you guys. Thanks.

Comment: I urge you to reconsider. Match against can use indexes but like %something% something cannot. You are going to be having horribly slow queries if you have more than a few thousand records.

Comment: Ill eventually end up repurposing the tables and data so that it'll be an employee database  in the with 190 or so records so it shouldn't be too long. What are your though on this

Comment: Yeah, for that number of records anything goes! You don't even need a primary key!! (just kidding about the primary key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For build a proper like clause you can use concat

```
$sql = "SELECT * from tbl_fish WHERE  fish_name LIKE concat ( '%', :searchQuery, '%')";
```

and for match the 3 columns you should use OR

```
$sql = "SELECT * from tbl_fish 
   WHERE  fish_name LIKE concat ( '%', :searchQuery, '%')
     or size_name   LIKE concat ( '%', :searchQuery, '%')
     or cat_name    LIKE concat ( '%', :searchQuery, '%');";
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, But now im getting Json errors such as
org.json.JSONException: Value <br> of type java.lang.String cannt be converted to JSONArray

when i go to test in android studio. what does this mean and how can i fix it

Comment: This last error is not related to the question you posted .. for this you should post another question specifically for your new problem  .. and if my answer is right is fair mark it as accepted

Comment: Sounds good thanks again mate. Since im new to this. what would i tag as that next question as then?

Comment: Well is JSON related i suggest PHP and JSON ENCODE  avoid refer to improper tag like you do with sqlserver .... if is mysql can't be sqlserver)